# Can you identify this font on metal plate?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I have seen this before but I cannot find it via Google Images, nor via other font identifiers. I know I used it before, back when my workstation was Windows. I have already traced the other object and I'm just lacking this type.

[image]

Comment: If you remember, was it a free font or paid font? The closest I found are "Bank Gothic Std Medium" and "Banker Square" font family. It is possible that same font is used but edited some letters like M and R manually. And italicized.

Comment: I agree, it looks like Bank Gothic but with a modified C and custom M, possibly from another font.